# Working with InstallShield 2010. How do you force a restart

Tags: installshield-2010

I have some prerequisites required, and one of the prerequisites requires a reboot if installed before the rest of the setup can continue.  Using InstallShield, how do you force a restart after prerequisites are installed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is an MSI installation looks like you need to initiate the [ForceReboot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368607%28VS.85%29.aspx) action to take place within the InstallShield script. Check the [Flexera Software KB](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/microsites/microsite.do?msid=MS_INSTALLATION_1_1) for additional details searching on *ForceReboot*.